# Постановка тире после "это"

Tags: пунктуация, тире

> Для стран — экспортеров, это (—) закрепление на стратегических рынках
> по экономически выгодным ценам, обеспечение капитала и финансирования
> инвестиций в инфраструктуру и разработку ресурсов [17].

Помогите, пожалуйста, кто знает: нужно ли здесь тире? Мне кажется, что нет.

Answer (score 4):

Запятой точно не нужно, тире же можно ставить, можно не ставить. При подлежащем, выраженном местоимением ЭТО, тире ставится или не ставится в зависимости от логического выделения подлежащего и наличия или отсутствия паузы после него.

*Это — начало всех начал. Это —  одиночество.*(Чехов)

*Это дом Зверкова* (Гоголь). *Это очень сложная проблема.*

Если это не художественный текст, нейтральный, лучше обойтись без интонационных тире, без эмоций, без лишних пауз.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

*Для стран-экспортеров - это закрепление на стратегических рынках по экономически выгодным ценам, обеспечение капитала и финансирования инвестиций в инфраструктуру и разработку ресурсов.*

Вот так.

Но такой вариант допустим только в ЕГЭ, сочинении и переписке с друзьями.